# convert date string to date time c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this confusion of converting 23/09/21 or 09/23/21 to a valid datetime

**23/09/21 refers to development environment** ,
**09/23/21 refers to customer deploy environment**

```
string _tmpCreatedDate = ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)b1MatrixUser.Columns.Item("Col_8").Cells.Item(i + 1).Specific).Value;
```

hence becomes `string _tmpCreatedDate = "23/09/21";`

```
DateTime _swapCreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_tmpCreatedDate);
```

above code will output string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

tried   `_tmpCreatedDate = Convert.ChangeType(_tmpCreatedDate, typeof(DateTime)).ToString();`

as well, same convert issue, as the input string is dynamic dd/MM/yy  or
MM/dd/yy
how to handle this in correct way?

Comment: You can't just change a type like this, you should look at [`DateTime.Parse`] or the other variants (`ParseExact`, `TryParse` etc)

Comment: What would you expect the result to be for "04/05/21"?

Comment: @JonSkeet that is the issue dd/MM/yy refers to development environment , MM/dd/yy refers to customer deploy environment , how to tackle this situation ?

Comment: Well, do you know which culture you should be using at any point? If so, use `DateTime.ParseExact` specifying the appropriate culture. But if you don't "know" which environment you're in, that's more of a problem. (I'd argue that a better solution if at all possible would be to change how the data is stored, but I realize that may be infeasible at this stage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added as comment, but to OP request, I am adding an answer:

You could specify date format in config in your application or detect in code, at app startup if it's development mode, then you can save appropriate format in some global variable.

One of ideas, if you're using dependency injection, would be to define some date provider service or even you could try specifying own `IFormatProvider` or something like that, and then using it in parsing methods of `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can simply use `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(_tmpCreatedDate , "MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Read more over here [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0)  and [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0)

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(_tmpCreatedDate , "MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); makes String was not recognized as a valid DateTime as trying to convert 23/09/21

Comment: try to change `MM/dd/yyyy` into `dd/MM/yyyy` and, let me know if its working

Comment: @Sanjeewa try to change `MM/dd/yyyy` into `dd/MM/yyyy` and, let me know if its working

Comment: it works for one environment only , i think have to think on ambiguity case mentioned above

Comment: Yuo could specify dat format in config in your application or detect in code, at app startup if it's developemnt mode, then you can save appropriate format in some global variable.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Yup, good point

Comment: @MichałTurczyn add above as the answer -> global variable.